# TextMate Code Formatter for C

Tags: c, coding-style

I am working on a C assignment for uni, and I've been coding in TextMate and compiling in the command line.

But TextMate wont (or cant) format C code, as it would for say, HTML, Ruby or PHP (using SHIFT + CTRL + F).

Is there a plugin or some other tool I can use to fix my indenting and curly braces for .c files?

Comment: Does this help? http://projects.serenity.de/textmate/tutorials/basics/#formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Eclipse for C/C++ Developers. If has a formatting functionality. You can also compile and test within the IDE by just clicking a button. With Helios, the most current Eclipse release, there are more features.

Enjoy.

Comment: Thats cool.  you know the funny thing is I am a NetBeans developer - and I love it.  It turns out NetBeans can do the formatting, so you gave me an idea - but i copied and paste to and fro to get the formatting I liked.  Problem solved.

But the interesting thing is that the more development I do on my Mac, the more I seem to be pushed towards Eclipse.  Is it really THAT good?

Answer (score 2):

I use [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/). It has a lot of options to customize according to your coding style, and I think it is included in the major linux distributions.

Answer (score 1):

`indent` is a command-line tool that will properly indent your C code.  It is highly customizable but its basic usage is `indent <input.c> <output.c>`.  See `man indent` for options.  Installed by default with Mac OS X Developer Tools, which I assume you have installed because you are writing C on a Mac.